# iOS7 UIProgressBar fill without delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I use UIProgressView in iOS7 and here is the problem: let's say for demonstration I have just UIProgressView and UIButton on the UIView. When button clicked next function fires:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick {
    if (self.progress.progress == 0) {
        self.progress.progress = 0.7;
    }
    else
    {
        self.progress.progress = 0;
    }
}
```

and what is bad, progress it is not drawn immediately, instead it is creeping from 0 to 0.7 which is of course beautiful, but not what I want right now. I try to change options in UI Builder, but nothing helped me so far.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make progress be drawn exactly the moment the button was clicked without any delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
 -(void)setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated
```

with `animated` set to `NO`.

Comment: +1 for the fastest correct answer. You beat me on that one ;-)

Comment: Haha, I was just late 10 secs...Need to speed up my typo :P

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.progress setProgress:0.7 animated:NO];
```